# Group and Members Management with Google Admin SDK

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

i have some problem to manage the Members with the Google API.
This code actually works fine:

```
    Collection<String> scopes = new LinkedList<String>();
    scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_ALIAS);
    scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);

    String adminMail = "admin.google@mydomain.com"; //This is a Super Admin User
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setServiceAccountId(serviceMail).setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).setServiceAccountUser(adminMail).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(privateKey)).build();

    Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(applicationName).build();    
    //User Management   
    User myUser= directory.users().get("admin.google@mydomain.com").execute(); //IT WORKS !!

    //Group Management
    String userEmail = "myMail@mydomain.com";
    Member member = new Member();
    member.setEmail(userEmail);
    member.setRole("MEMBER");
    String groupID = "testGroup1@mydomain.com";
    directory.members().insert(groupID, member).execute(); //DOES NOT WORK
```

But when i try to manage the member or groups i obtain this permission error:

```
  com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
```

If I try to ADD the following scopes:

```
Collection<String> scopes = new LinkedList<String>();
scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_ALIAS);
scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);
scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP);
scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER);
```

I obtain this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
 com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
 com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:96)
 com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
 com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
 com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
 com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
 com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
 com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
 com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
 com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
 main.java.MioMain.main(MioMain.java:77)
```

Does not work the User Search and the Group Member Insert.
Could you help me ?

Comment: I changed the jar from: **google-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc** to **google-oauth-client-1.22.0** and now i obtain: _Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized_. I tried to add all the scopes: `for (String s : DirectoryScopes.all()) {
      //System.out.println(s);
      scopes.add(s);
  }`         but nothing works.

Comment: Check that those scopes are also added in https://admin.google.com/yourdomain/ManageOauthClients

Comment: This error `403 Insufficient Permission` is an error regarding the scopes that you use. Try only to use the [scope](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing) `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group"` because it is the global scope for access to all group operations, including group aliases and members. Also note that to request access using OAuth 2.0, your application needs the scope information, as well as information that Google supplies when you register your application (such as the client ID and the client secret).

Comment: @KENdi I tried only with the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group` but nothing. I have always 403 Insufficient Permission. With the scope **DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER** works only the modify/search person but nothing with group. With the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group` nothing works.